# Jenkins spawn new process

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cicd

I want to spawn a new process AFTER a build was succesful (Freestyle project) to start (for example) a server or a discord bot.

Currently the build starts and starts the program in the job so it doesn't funish and just runs forever

(I am new to jenkins please don't blame me)

I'm on Windows btw

I already tried using `start /B <program>` and `start "" <program>` as build step

I found the Plugin [PostBuildScript](https://plugins.jenkins.io/postbuildscript/) and tried using it. I can run Windows Batch Commands there but it still runs in the build and the build doesn't end.

I could choose between `Master`, `Slave` or `Both`. `Master` and `Both` did the exact same things I don't want and `Slave` didn't work at all.

Comment: Show us Jenkinsfile.

Comment: I don't have one I think. I never created one and I am using a Freestyle Porject.